# Access static resource in other osgi bundle?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, bundle, equinox

I have created two OSGi bundles B1 and B2 (Equinox).

In the bundle B1 I have a directory `WebContent/WEB-INF/WEB.xml` under root directory.

```
source.. = src/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\.,\WebContent
```

In the manifest of bundle B2 I have added bundle B1 as a dependency. I would like to make `WebContent` and it's subtree visible for bundle B2.

NOTE:

1. I can't export `WebContent` in manifest of B1 as it's not in `src` folder.
2. If I put `WebContent/WEB-INF` in `src` folder, I still can't export it as `WebContent/WEB-INF` as it's not a valid package name.

Comment: Would it be an option to make B1 a fragment?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had the problem, but [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-73025.html) seems like it addresses the same issue

Comment: @Björn Pollex: no, B1 must be a bundle.

Comment: I am actually want to add OSGi nature in WebAPP.

Answer (score 3):

Can you get a reference to the B1 bundle? If so I think you can use [getEntry](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29). E.g.

```
Bundle b1 = /* get bundle here */
URL urlToWebXml = b1.getEntry("WebContent/WEB-INF/WEB.xml");
```

'get bundle here' might get access to the Bundle via your B2 Bundle's activator which probably stores the BundleContext.

Comment: The leading slash in the path is not needed (in fact strictly should not be there). Otherwise the answer is good.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I edited the answer. When I wrote the answer I wasn't sure whether to include the slash or not; the Javadocs say any string is relative to the root so I suppose including it is redundant.